# VS2012 Breakpoints are not getting hit

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class MyService
{
    private MyService(){}
    public static string GetStuff()
    {
        var stuffDid = new MyService();
        return stuffDid.DoStuff();
    }
    private string DoStuff()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    //other private helpers

}
```

Obviously I left a lot out, but that's the general shell.

Now, I have a unit test:

```
[Test]
public void MyTest()
{

    var results = MyService.GetStuff();
}
```

I set breakpoints on my unit test, and I can see that `results` has data. However, I set breakpoints literally all over `MyService` and nothing gets hit unless I put them on a curly brace. Which I can't understand since `results` has data, my `return` statements in `MyService` should be getting hit, right?

Am I missing something? Did I completely forgot the most basic rules of something? How come nothing in `MyService` gets hit? And if I manually step into it with `F11`, it just hops around and doesn't even go through every line like I would expect. Also when I step through manually I tend to hit certain code after I should have hit it originally. And any `switch` statements seem to default to whatever the first option is, even though the value being switched should CLEARLY enter a different `case`.

I've even tried making `MyService` constructor `public` and taking away all `static` methods, and it still doesn't work.

My Tests and 'Core' code are in the same solution, but different projects(`Test` and `Core`, respectively). Other tests don't have an issue hitting break points in `Core`, only this on particular test (the only test that is testing `MyService`).

I've deleted my PDB files and cleaned solution. Still nothing.

Comment: Do you have a circle thingy (not sure if it is only for NUnit) in your tests? If you do, click on it, and click debug.. it should work then.

Comment: Is the code in the same solution? Visual Studio's debugger has a "just my code" option. Not sure on the specifics of how it works.

Comment: Are the imports correct?  Can your unit test see the project code or just the compiled dll?

Comment: Yes, all code is in the same solution. My tests are in a separate project(called Tests), but other tests don't seem to have an issue hitting breakpoints in Core(where the code is that won't get hit).

Comment: I am not sure but it looks like the debug symbols are off: Can you try to debug again after doing the following steps: (1) Build the "Core" project first. (2) Then run the test solution. See if it hits the breakpoint.

Comment: Do you have any try/catch blocks that might be swallowing an exception causing something in your operation chain to be skipped?

Comment: does your code actually do what you expect? add a `Console.WriteLine("hello")` somewhere. Do you see that in the output?

Comment: You should check the code run by the testrunner is actually the latest version of the code. Try calling the test from a "normal" exe file to see if there is any difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out this was related to Code Coverage being on.

Turning it off fixed the issue.

You can find out how to disable code coverage by following below link

[Disable code coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301817/how-can-i-disable-code-coverage-assembly-instrumentation-in-visual-studio-2012)

Comment: This isn't really an answer. You should describe how you turned off Code Coverage.

Answer (score 62):

Some ideas.

1. Make sure it's a debug build and not release
2. Turn off optimizations in your project properties if they are on
3. Try inserting `Debugger.Break()` in your code instead of a breakpoint
   in VS
4. Make sure breakpoints are enabled (Debug->Windows->Breakpoints toolbar), and breakpoint symbol should be solid
5. Execute your application. **Load Debug->Window->Modules window.** Check your assembly to see if symbols are loaded. It may give a relevant status message if not.

Have you been adjusting the date on your computer at all? This can really screw up a build process. If so, delete all your obj/bin folders manually and recompile.

Comment: I just ran into another case: .NET Framework version mismatch between assemblies in the solution. Test assembly was .NET 4.5, tested assembly was .NET 3.5, couldn't set breakpoints in either. Fixed by converting test assembly back to 3.5.

Comment: I don't understand the 5th step.  I can open up Debug > Window > Modules, but what do I do from there?  How can I check my assembly to see if symbols are loaded?

Comment: Deleting `/obj` worked for me after messing with the system date - thanks!

Comment: I had the opposite issue, my breakpoints were only hitting on actual code and not on opening or closing curly braces of the method bodies. Removing the 'tick' from 'Optimize code' under the project's Properties > Build > General, is what did the trick. Thanks @Alan

Answer (score 11):

It could be beacuse you are only debugging 1 project not both `Test` and `Core`

You can set VS to debug mutiple projects at once, you can do this by `right-click your solution > Properties > Common Properties > StartUp Project`

Here you can set "Multiple Startup Projects" 
[image]

Just set both `Core` and `Test` to start. This may solve your issue.

Answer (score 5):

I have a very specific scenario that resulted in the apparent issue of "Breakpoint not being hit".

Since no other answers here mentioned it, I will add mine in the chance that it will help someone who had the same issue.

The solution, in my case, was silly, and with as much LINQ as I use I should have figured this out sooner.  When running a method that returns an IEnumerable, where the return statements contained within are actually `yield return` statements, then that method will not be executed when you call it.

It will actually be executed when you call another method from that IEnumerable object, such as `ToList()` or `Count()`.  Only *then* will the method be executed and the breakpoint reached.

Comment: I always forget that, then Google, then find an answer like this, then remind myself not to forget that...

Answer (score 3):

Just make sure that you have build your assembly with the debugger symbols.

This option has to be filled with "full":

Right-Click your project containing your code file with the break points not getting hit. Choose "Properties".

After project properties have been opened, choose "Build" tab. Watch out for the "Advanced..."-Buttom at the bottom of the tab page. (Within the "Output"-Group")

Click this button and choose "full" for the "Debug info" property. This should be a reason for breakpoints not getting hit. Visual studio uses the symbols saved in the pdb-files to find the exact position of the break point. If these files are not created, no breakpoints are hit. Maybe you disabled the creation of these files in order to tidy up your project file structure. This was a situation I recognized that I need these files.

Comment: Are you using services as they appear in the windows services list? If so, you may have to debug by hitting Debug -> "Attach to process" instead of simple debugging.

Answer (score 3):

I've recently had the same problem and was smashing my head against the wall.

The answer turned out to be pretty silly: Somehow my test project got out of sync with the main library project. I was building the debug versions of the test and library, but the test project copied the library from the `bin/Release` folder. I just recreated the project reference and everything was fixed.

P.S. It was even criazier: the debugger went inside a library function, but somehow skipped one line in the middle of it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make DoStuff static.

```
private static string DoStuff()
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Sorry, made an edit to my code, so I'm not sure making DoStuff static is necessary.

Comment: well not now that you updated your code to instantiate a class variable to call the method from ;) Also notice that your constructor is private, it should be public unless you only plan on calling it from the static method.

Comment: Well the constructor is private so the only way to access the class is thru the static public method(I need to follow this pattern, unfortunately).

Answer (score 1):

Your code indicates a "service", which could be running as a separate process. If that's the case you can have your assembly loaded, so breakpoints would be solid red circles but another copy of the assembly, running in a separate process is actually handling the requests.

- check Task Manager for possible offenders (processes that may be hosting your service). Kill them while debugging to confirm the calls fail.
- Try using Debugger.Break();
- Create a debug log file, upon loading output to the log the entry process and assembly names. Make sure your log is either a different file each time to avoid async access issues.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the pdb files are not updated in your test sandbox.

1) Ensure that you are in debug mode.

2) Can you try and include a deployment item for the pdb files explicitly?

- You said that you can attach a debug point in your test project.
- Once you have hit the debug point in your test project , check to make sure the pdb files with the latest time stamp is present in the Out folder of your sandbox.

3) If 1 and 2 fail , I have found that sometimes visual studio requires a restart :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Clean the solution and rebuild and also do the start up project.
2. Can you please have a quick look at the BUILD > Configuration Manager, just to sure what are the configuration properties are set up. If it is development then you might have to adjust the Project Properties -> click advance setting -> change debug info to 'full' in [output tab].
3. you can also follow step two even it is not development mode

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen in a 1 project out of 25 which were all in the same solution. The other projects honored breakpoints but this 1 didn't. I removed the project from the solution (delete, not unload) which broke all references to it and then added it back to the solution and that worked!

If that doesn't work you may want to recreate the problem project from scratch and add that new project to the solution.

The best explanation I have for why this worked apart from pure luck is that we migrated projects from one version of VS to another many, many times over the years and maybe one of those migrations caused this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a `Thread.Sleep(5000)` in `GetStuff` method and use Attach to Process

**Visual Studio > Tools > Attach To Process** and see if breakpoints below that line gets hit.

Comment: Using the method `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` will be far more simpler to attach a process at a very specific point.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in release mode switch it to debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

I know from experience that Visual Studio does not have a clear method of debugging services, especially Windows services. Try adding some code to GetStuff to print to a text file, this way you at least know the code is getting hit. When creating services I often fall back on this method for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue.  It turned out that for me it was a bad migration from VS2010 to VS2012 with the `*.testrunconfig` file.  I deleted the old one and set up a new one to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

VS behaves exactly the way you described (not hitting the breakpoints, hitting the code you're not expecting to hit when stepping through) when it uses .pdb file which was generated using the source code somehow different from the code which is used upon debugging. I can't guarantee that this is your case, but I've observed such behaviour many times when I needed to step into the code which was supplied as a pre-built library which was generated against an older/different code with same filenames/symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `Test` project is referencing an older `Core` binary, rather than the `Core` (source code) project?

Try re-adding the reference in your Test project:

Go to your `Test` project and remove the reference to the `Core` project.

Now select the References folder and right click it and select the menu option to add a new reference.  When in the Reference Manager dialog, make sure you are selecting `Solution` and then `Projects` on the left.  Then in the middle of the Reference Manager dialog, select (check) the `Core` project.

Try debugging again and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Some more stuff to try:

- Check if the loaded symbols match the debugged executable:
  Open a VS command prompt and cd to the directory where the executable you debug resides.
  Then do a `dumpbin /PDBPATH:VERBOSE MyServiceExecutable.exe` and scan the output for "PDB age mismatch" (Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44wx0fef.aspx)
- Not sure about VS 2012, but older versions of VS had a bug where the wrong source file would be displayed, provided that you have two source files in your project that have the same
  name, even when they are located in different folders. So if your project contains another source file with the same name, see if renaming one of them helps. (*Update:* Seems VS 2012 [is affected too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12416192/1097883).)

Answer (score 0):

Silly me the Test Project wasn't set to be built:

[image]

Comment: TIP: you can just stick a 'throw new Exception()` in your code instead of a breakpoint to make sure your code is really compiling. If the latest version of your code isn't running then this could be the culprit

Answer (score 0):

This one's pretty obscure :

Make sure you don't have two virtual directories with different App Pools pointing to the same physical location on your harddrive. During development this is something that can sometimes happen for testing, or by mistake.

I'm not 100% clear on the technicalities but I had two AppPools and two virtual directories and no breakpoint was ever hit because I presume the physical path was somehow mapped in IIS/Visual Studio to the other apppool and not the one that was actually executing.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Maybe my solution will help you to solve your problem. Just in "Attach to Process" for option "Attach to" select value "Avtomatic: Native code". Best regards.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First try rebuilding your project by right mouse click the project > Rebuild If that doesn't work, try a clean of the project (right mouse click on the project > clean)

If that didn't work check this:

```
Right mouse click your project
select [Properties]
select the [Build] tab
make sure [Define DEBUG constant] and [Define TRACE constant] are checked
Click the [Advanced] button at the bottom of the Build tabpage
Make sure that [Debug Info:] is set to [full]
Click [OK] and rebuild the project ;-)
```

Hope that works for you! (step 6 generates the .pdb files, these are the debugging symbols)

Answer (score 0):

To debug step-by-step, you must do two things. First you must set the break point, then you must attach the debugger to the process running your code. If you are running IIS Express and you have 64 bit machine, then you need to attach **iisexpress.exe** that is running your code. If you press CTRL + ALT + P, you'll get to the attach to process window. After attaching, the break point should be hit if the code matches.

Answer (score 0):

In Unit Tests, I was not hitting breakpoints, and realized I was Running the test and not Debugging the test. At the top of the Test Explorer are the options "Run All", "Run Failed", "Run Passed", etc. When you Run a test, breakpoints are not hit. To Debug a test, in the Test Explorer right click on the test or group of tests and select Debug Selected Tests.

Comment: "Debug Selected Tests" works for me and triggers the breakpoints :).