# Visual Studio 2012 Breakpoints do not hit

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013

I have made a simple visual webpart for SharePoint 2013 in visual studio 2012. The `.apsx` page only has one label.Then i say deploy and attach to process `w3wp` and refresh the webpage where i have added the visual webpart.In the code i have put breakpoints at the start on `oninit()` and `pageload()` methods. But when i refresh the page i find the label but the code behind does not run and the breakpoints are not hit.
When i hover the break points i get following message.
[image]

Comment: where is your "following message"

Comment: its in the image the one in yellow

Comment: Ok, did not see the image

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas.

1. Make sure it's a debug build and not release
2. Turn off optimizations in your project properties if they are on
3. Try inserting `Debugger.Break()` in your code instead of a breakpoint
   in VS
4. Make sure breakpoints are enabled (Debug->Windows->Breakpoints toolbar), and breakpoint symbol should be solid
5. Execute your application. **Load Debug->Window->Modules window.** Check your assembly to see if symbols are loaded. It may give a relevant status message if not.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025734/vs2012-breakpoints-are-not-getting-hit)