# Unable to debug aspx page

Tags: asp.net, debugging

Everything worked normally untill yesterday. Today morning when I tried to debug java script function (in aspx), it is not hitting the debug points...

I thought debug thing is not working ..so to test I added debug points in code behind file..it is firing them..the only problem is with aspx page..

I tried the following:

Clean solution Re-Build..
close and re open visual studio..
Restart my machine..
iisreset

I am confused what might be the reason..Can anybody please help me out?

Comment: Without seeing the code, and an example of the error, no, we really can't help.

Comment: What are you using to debug the JavaScript?  I know Visual Studio *claims* to be able to do this, but personally I find browser-based debugging tools to be far more effective and reliable.

Comment: Iam just putting a debug point using cursor...i also tried writing 'debugger' in the very first line of that javascript function

Comment: @durbnpoisn..there was no error applications works fine,..its just that the debug points that were set in aspx page are not firing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem recently and this checklist helped me solve my issue:

Some ideas.

1. Make sure it's a debug build and not release
2. Turn off optimizations in your project properties if they are on
3. Try inserting Debugger.Break() in your code instead of a breakpoint in VS
4. Make sure breakpoints are enabled (Debug->Windows->Breakpoints toolbar), and breakpoint symbol should be solid red circle, not a red outline of a circle
5. Execute your application. Load Debug->Window->Modules window. Check your assembly to see if symbols are loaded. It may give a relevant status message if not.

Have you been adjusting the date on your computer at all? This can really screw up a build process. If so, delete all your obj/bin folders manually and recompile.

This was copied from the an answer found in this post:
[VS2012 Breakpoints are not getting hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025734/vs2012-breakpoints-are-not-getting-hit)

There are many other helpful suggestions there as well, im sure one of them should work!

Answer (score -1):

In your aspx, find the tag `<script runat="server">.....abx xyz... </script>` then delete the content of this tag.