# symbols are created but debugging never stops at break point

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

**How do I get my breakpoints working?**

I am getting this message when running a C# console app in debug mode:

[image]

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded
>   for this document.

Here are other specs related to this issue:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25123.00 Update
>   2 Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01055
>
> Installed Version: Professional
>
> ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)   14.1.11106.0 ASP.NET and Web
>   Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0 For additional
>   information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.40314.0 For additional
>   information, visit http://www.asp.net/
>
> Code alignment   12.1 Code alignment helps you present your code
>   beautifully, enhancing clarity and readability.
>
> CodeMaid   10.1.93 CodeMaid is an open source Visual Studio extension
>   to cleanup and simplify our C#, C++, F#, VB, PHP, PowerShell, R, JSON,
>   XAML, XML, ASP, HTML, CSS, LESS, SCSS, JavaScript and TypeScript
>   coding.
>
> Common Azure Tools   1.7 Provides common services for use by Azure
>   Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.
>
> ConfigurationTransform   1.3 Automatically transform app.config during
>   build process. Once the transformation is set, it will run on other
>   build machines without the extension.
>
> GitHub.VisualStudio   1.0 A Visual Studio Extension that brings the
>   GitHub Flow into Visual Studio.
>
> JavaScript Language Service   2.0 JavaScript Language Service
>
> JavaScript Project System   2.0 JavaScript Project System
>
> JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 10.0.2   Build 104.0.20151218.120627
>   JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate package for Microsoft Visual Studio. For
>   more information about ReSharper Ultimate, visit
>   http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper. Copyright © 2016 JetBrains, Inc.
>
> Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4 Microsoft Azure Mobile
>   Services Tools
>
> Node.js Tools   1.1.31117.00 Adds support for developing and debugging
>   Node.js apps in Visual Studio
>
> Node.js Tools - Profiling   1.1.31117.00 Profiling support for Node.js
>   projects.
>
> NuGet Package Manager   3.4.3 NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.
>   For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.
>
> NuGet References   1.0 Save time by managing your NuGet references
>   right from the Solution Explorer packages.config
>
> PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2 Microsoft Visual Studio
>   extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive
>   Analytics product.
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.60311.1 Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
>
> StyleCop   4.7 Provides source code style and consistency tools. See
>   https://github.com/Visual-Stylecop/Visual-StyleCop for more details.
>
> TypeScript   1.8.30.0 TypeScript tools for Visual Studio

Here are my debugging settings:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here are my settings for the projects:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here are the packages I am using:

```
 <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Magnum" version="2.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="MassTransit" version="2.9.9" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="MassTransit.Log4Net" version="2.9.9" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="MassTransit.MSMQ" version="2.9.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.6" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Other references not covered by nuget:

[image]

1. The solution is made up of 2 projects: consoleProject, classLibraryProject.
2. consoleProject references classLibraryProject.
3. When going to debug->windows->Modules for classLibraryProject I am getting the message "Could not find or open the PDB file.
4. When manually building the PDB for classLibraryProject and moving it into the bin\Debug for consoleProject, then I get a symbol status of "Symbols Loaded." **However, the breakpoints are not honored. **
5. Yes, I am certain that the code is triggered because the side effects of the code are visible.

**How do I get my breakpoints working?**

Comment: I almost feel like if you haven't experienced this problem then you haven't been to the school of hard knocks. I get this all the time. I usually just violently shake my machine until it decides to work.

Comment: I guess you cleaned the entire solution, rebuilt and restarted VS?

Comment: @MattiasÅslund yes indeed

Comment: Are both of your projects targeting .NET 4 or higher?

Comment: Go to Tools | Options | Debugging | Just-in-Time and uncheck everything but script.

Comment: Is this behavior specific to this given application? Or this happens for all solutions in your VS install?

Comment: @ChrisO yes they are higher than 4

Comment: @ChrisO tried that already

Comment: @Tamas-SonarSourceTeam this is solution specific

Comment: I can't see any strange settings in your setup. I'd simplify the solution to create a minimal repro. Then start from scratch, add the references, create the same repro and see if that produces the same behavior. I'd also check the csproj files and app.config for any strange settings.

Comment: When you compile, PDB files (for both projects) are created in bin/debug folder? are you running any post build steps changing anything?

Comment: If you haven't already, can you try these instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14075051/2346893

Comment: Hard to guess how you "manually build the PDB" or why it has to be copied by hand.  At bullet 3, right click the DLL in the modules list and select "Symbol Load Information".  Paste what you see in your question.  Do not obfuscate anything.

Comment: Do you use Code Contracts? If they are enabled turn them off.

Comment: how are you referring the classlibrary from the consoleproject? project reference or dll reference? As @Artyom mentions in his answer, reference is not seen in the screenshot you shared.

Answer (score 2):

I just created new console app + class library. Please be sure that console app has reference on class library (like on image)

[image]

I wrote that because I don't see that on your screens.

Than plz right click on solution and select "properties..."
You will see smth like that:
[image]
Check that configuration + platform are equal for your projects and that checkboxes 'Build' are both selected. If that checkboxes are selected then after 'clean build' of you solution you will see smth like that in the bin\Debug folder of colsole app:

[image]

Please notice that class library has 2 files (highlighted on screen): dll + pdb. In that case dll+pdb are in synchro state and your breakepoints will work in class library code.

If you have no pdb file for class library project after build than may be your reference on class library is NOT a reference on a VS project. Please check that you added reference correctly (like on image):

[image]

DO NOT reference on dll file of class library directly via 'Browse' dialog.

You can check that your console app refenced correctly on class library project - please open console app csproj file on edit and look on reference:

[image]

If you have BAD refence (on a .dll file):

[image]

than delete that reference via context menu in VS and add a correct one.

I hope that will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have my sympathy for trying to fix this. When I compare settings with mine I find 2 differences in Debugging|General:

1. check: Suppress JIT optimization on module load
2. uncheck: Load dll exports

The first one may fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are different reasons why this could happen. I had the same problem and one of the possible solutions was to delete all .pdb and .idb files

Answer (score 1):

did you try unchecking the option Debugging > general > Require source file to exactly match the original version ?

Comment: I did not but why why would I?

Comment: sometimes the source code are different then the code loaded in bin while debugging, so it hinders in debugging, you can try this one.

Comment: Very interesting. Will try and let you know

Comment: did you try that? any luck?

Answer (score 1):

Just thinking out loud, I have come across the following that has meant no debugging:
These are general situations and not particular to any environment.

- System running low on memory and so the JIT does not go into debugging mode. Increase where possible memory settings for the server.
- Deployment is not replacing the old version somehow, bypass the build script and physically remove the artefact manually. Create a new artefact and deploy that also manually.
- Build scripts are not overwritting old classes/binaries and these are being sourced from a maven style cache or other warehouse. Remove any references to these files and try again.
- Classes are being built but these are not being wrapped up into the final object, again remove the final object and adjust the build script to remove this error.
- Versioning (some servers) is not allowing the new artefact to be deployed, ensure the version is incremented per deploy and try again.
- The server you are deploying on is not where you are connecting to per debug session, either wrong port or other listening issue. Stop the server to see if the session is indeed where you think it is.
- Also from versioning, if your dated artefact is not in line with the server date - so an hour behind for example then it may not deploy again or the deployments will be erratic.

If I think of others I will be post here.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem in framework code before.  Try this:

1. Go to Debug -> Windows -> Breakpoints
2. In the Breakpoint window, click New -> Break at Function
3. Enter the fully-qualified method name.

That should at least get you a breakpoint at the start of the method that you can then step through.

Note that I always get an error message that tells me the breakpoint won't work when I use this technique.  But it works anyway.

Note that I did have valid symbols loaded, so be sure to use your setup that tells you your symbols are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you are attaching to both processes.  Visual Studio by default will only attach to the startup project.  It appears that consoleProject is your startup project.  After you start debugging consoleProject use the `Debug` menu and select `"Attach to Process..."` and choose the process corresponding to classLibraryProject.  The breakpoints will now be available.

`Ctl+Alt+P` is the shortcut key for this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem just like this not too long ago ... and I am not really sure which of the things I performed actually solved the problem.

But what I can tell is that I found that (although the `packages.config` entries were looking ok) several (!) used libraries were not in the proper .net version (`net461` in my case).

I used a tool called **Target Framework Migrator** to fix this. You can get it through Tools => extensions and updates => Online => Visual Studio Gallery

and then type `Target Framework Migrator` in the Search Field.

I do remember, that I also upgraded .Net to 4.6.1 during my attempts to fix the problem ... maybe you could try this too ... but in any case running the Target Framework Migrator for your own Libraries (and restarting VS 2015 on the way) is definitely worth a try.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to click on that button which is to the left of the device button,

[image]

And I selected edit scheme from the drop down menu

[image]

I then selected Run from the list on the left of the pop-up, and checked the box "debug executable" (it was unchecked previously)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your configuration is set to Debug, not Release.

Try this if above is correct: Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols and check "Microsoft Symbol Servers"

Answer (score -1):

With anomalies like this it is well worth cleaning the solution (including manually deleting bin and obj folders then rebooting.